# Concatenate Regular Expressions

Tags: sql, regex

I have a situation where a string should match one pattern or the other. I tried several options, but none works. If I use both patterns independently they work, but when I concatenate using Pipe ["|"] operator, outcome is not correct. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Select 'P' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE('W777AA,WZGET0,WZGEG0','(^W[0-9A-Z]{5}(,W[0-9A-Z]{5}){0,3}$)')
Select 'P' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE('WZGET%','%$')
```

Concatenate SQL:

```
Select 'P' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE ('W777AA,WZGET0,WZGEG0','(^W[0-9A-Z]{5}(,W[0-9A-Z]{5}){0,3}$ | (%$))')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smells like an order of operations issue.  Try throwing in some parens, something like this: 
`Concatenate SQL: Select 'P' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE
  ('W777AA,WZGET0,WZGEG0','((^W[0-9A-Z]{5}(,W[0-9A-Z]{5}){0,3}$)|(%$))')`

Comment: Tried..It doesn't work..Getting an error of Unbalanced Parentheses when copied and Pasted.

Then balanced the parentheses without any success.

Comment: This seems to work now...at least in Ruby's regex parser:  http://rubular.com/r/rpZC6HL4fd